# How to group or classify values in a column in R?

Tags: r

How to group or classify values in a column in R?

The target variable loan_status has a few values as can be seen below.

- Curremt
- Fully Paid
- Charged Off
- Late (31 - 120 days)
- In Grace Period
- Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Fully Paid Late (16-30 days)
- Default
- Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Charged Off

I would like to classify loans with the following loan_status values as being in default (bad, or 1):

- Charged Off
- Default
- Late (31–120 days)
- Does not meet the creditpolicy. Status:Charged Off

All the other values will be classified as good (or 0).

Comment: Please do not add pictures of data. We cannot copy it to test our answers. A reproducible example with `dput` along with expected output would be helpful. Read about how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grepl` to convert the column into logical and then coerce it to binary with `+`

```
 df1$Flag <- +(grepl('Charged Off|Default|Late.* 31-120|Does not meet the credit policy', df1$loan_status))
```